# PyQt and context menu

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, menu

I need to create a context menu on right clicking at my window. But I really don't know how to achieve that.

Are there any widgets for that, or I have to create it from the beginning?

Programming language: Python
Graphical lib: Qt (PyQt)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I can't speak for python, but it's fairly easy in C++.

first after creating the widget you set the policy:

```
w->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
```

then you connect the context menu event to a slot:

```
connect(w, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &)), this, SLOT(ctxMenu(const QPoint &)));
```

Finally, you implement the slot:

```
void A::ctxMenu(const QPoint &pos) {
    QMenu *menu = new QMenu;
    menu->addAction(tr("Test Item"), this, SLOT(test_slot()));
    menu->exec(w->mapToGlobal(pos));
}
```

that's how you do it in c++ , shouldn't be too different in the python API.

**EDIT:** after looking around on google, here's the setup portion of my example in python:

```
self.w = QWhatever();
self.w.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
self.connect(self.w,SIGNAL('customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)'), self.ctxMenu)
```

Comment: note that in the PyQt4, CustomContextMenu location in the package is here: PyQt4.QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu

Comment: Gotta love the random downvote after two years and 19 upvotes :-P

Comment: The downvote was accidental and I'm really really sorry.  The answer actually helped me a lot.

Comment: @UtkarshSinha See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127218/how-can-i-cancel-my-vote , it should work for downvotes as it does for upvotes. tl;dr: click the arrow again.

Answer (score 15):

Another example which shows how to use actions in a toolbar and context menu.

```
class Foo( QtGui.QWidget ):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, None)
        mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        # Toolbar
        toolbar = QtGui.QToolBar()
        mainLayout.addWidget(toolbar)

        # Action are added/created using the toolbar.addAction
        # which creates a QAction, and returns a pointer..
        # .. instead of myAct = new QAction().. toolbar.AddAction(myAct)
        # see also menu.addAction and others
        self.actionAdd = toolbar.addAction("New", self.on_action_add)
        self.actionEdit = toolbar.addAction("Edit", self.on_action_edit)
        self.actionDelete = toolbar.addAction("Delete", self.on_action_delete)
        self.actionDelete.setDisabled(True)

        # Tree
        self.tree = QtGui.QTreeView()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.tree)
        self.tree.setContextMenuPolicy( Qt.CustomContextMenu )
        self.connect(self.tree, QtCore.SIGNAL('customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint&)'), self.on_context_menu)

        # Popup Menu is not visible, but we add actions from above
        self.popMenu = QtGui.QMenu( self )
        self.popMenu.addAction( self.actionEdit )
        self.popMenu.addAction( self.actionDelete )
        self.popMenu.addSeparator()
        self.popMenu.addAction( self.actionAdd )

    def on_context_menu(self, point):

         self.popMenu.exec_( self.tree.mapToGlobal(point) )
```

Comment: Thanks @PedroMorgan for this - I found some code online using "_SIGNAL("customContextMenuRequest ... _", and was wondering why it doesn't work `:)` - thanks to this post, I know now it is called `customContextMenuRequested`, with "ed" at end... Cheers!

Comment: I know this is an old post, but the example given by PedroMorgan does not work for me. I have done so many searches on google and this is the closest I have got.

All I get when I Right click the list is a little box one pixel in size when I right click.

Can anyone point me to a more recent example of using context menus in PyQt which is demonstrated as simply as this one by Pedro.

Comment: It's so long ago that I cant rememebr where I got working code from, but I did get my code working in the end. Thanks