# Qt - Pop up menu

Tags: qt, menu, popup

I have added a label as an image(icon) to a widget in Qt.
I want to display a pop-up menu when the user clicks (left or right click) on the label.
How can I achieve this ? Please help...

Comment: What do you want exactly : a pop up menu when contextual menu is requested (right click), or a pop up menu whenever the label is clicked, no matter if it's the left or right button ?

Answer (score 7):

You'll want to set the `ContextMenuPolicy` of the widget, then connect the `customContextMenuRequested` event to some slot which will display the menu.

See: [Qt and context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782255/qt-and-context-menu/782462#782462)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to display a context menu whenever the label is clicked (with any mouse button), I guess you'll have to implement your own `Label` class, inheriting `QLabel` and handling the popup menu by yourself in case of a mouse event.

Here is a very simplified (but working) version :

```
class Label : public QLabel
{
public:
    Label(QWidget* pParent=0, Qt::WindowFlags f=0) : QLabel(pParent, f) {};
    Label(const QString& text, QWidget* pParent = 0, Qt::WindowFlags f = 0) : QLabel(text, pParent, f){};

protected :
    virtual void mouseReleaseEvent ( QMouseEvent * ev ) {
        QMenu MyMenu(this);
        MyMenu.addActions(this->actions());
        MyMenu.exec(ev->globalPos());
    }
};
```

This specialized `Label` class will display in the popup menu all actions added to it.

Let's say the main window of your application is called `MainFrm` and is displaying the label (`label`. Here is how the constructor would look :

```
MainFrm::MainFrm(QWidget *parent) : MainFrm(parent), ui(new Ui::MainFrm)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QAction* pAction1 = new QAction("foo", ui->label);
    QAction* pAction2 = new QAction("bar", ui->label);
    QAction* pAction3 = new QAction("test", ui->label);
    ui->label->addAction(pAction1);
    ui->label->addAction(pAction2);
    ui->label->addAction(pAction3);
    connect(pAction1, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(onAction1()));
    connect(pAction2, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(onAction2()));
    connect(pAction3, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(onAction3()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a label is clickable, it is logically a "textual **button**" and not a "**label**" any more.

I would suggest to use QToolButton instead, and use QSS to make up the toolbutton to a label.

```
#define SS_TOOLBUTTON_TEXT(_normal, _hover, _disabled) \
  "QToolButton" "{" \
    "background:transparent" \
    "color:" #_normal ";" \
  "}" \
  "QToolButton:hover" "{" \
    "color:" #_hover ";" \
  "}" \
  "QToolButton:disabled" "{" \
    "color:" #_disabled ";" \
  "}"

....

QToolButton *b = new QToolButton; {
  b->setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextOnly);
  b->setStyleSheet(SS_TOOLBUTTON_TEXT(blue, red, gray));
  b->setText(QString("[%1]").arg(tr("menu"));
}
b->setMenu(menu_to_popup);
connect(b, SIGNAL(clicked()), b, SLOT(showMenu()));
```