# Pop up menu in QT

Tags: qt, menu, popup

I have added a widget as a label (image or icon) to QT Main window.I need to display a pop up menu after I click (left or right click) on the label.Help please

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pop up menu in QT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778961/pop-up-menu-in-qt)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt - Pop up menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778961/qt-pop-up-menu)

Answer (score 2):

reimplement `mousePressEvent`

```
void YourWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QMenu menu(this);
    QAction *action = menu.addAction("action");
    if (menu.exec(event->pos()) == action) {
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Next time I promise to google for the answers before asking");
    }
}
```

you may also use event filters to handle the mouse click events from the widgets that you dont derive from, i.e. if you have q plain QLabel, and you want to add a context menu to it. Read up in assistant about `QObject::installEventFilter`