# Multiple Context menus in PyQt based on mouse location

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have a window with multiple tables using QTableWidget (PyQt).  I created a popup menu using the right click mouse and it works fine. 
However, I need to create different popup menu based on which table the mouse is hovering over at the time the right mouse is clicked. How can I get the mouse to tell me which table it is hovering over?

or, put in another way, how to implement a method so as to have a specific context menu based on mouse location?

I am using Python and PyQt.

My popup menu is developed similar to this code (PedroMorgan answer from [Qt and context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782255/qt-and-context-menu)):

```
class Foo( QtGui.QWidget ):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, None)

        # Toolbar
        toolbar = QtGui.QToolBar()

        # Actions
        self.actionAdd = toolbar.addAction("New", self.on_action_add)
        self.actionEdit = toolbar.addAction("Edit", self.on_action_edit)
        self.actionDelete = toolbar.addAction("Delete", self.on_action_delete)

        # Tree
        self.tree = QtGui.QTreeView()
        self.tree.setContextMenuPolicy( Qt.CustomContextMenu )
        self.connect(self.tree, QtCore.SIGNAL('customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint&)'), self.on_context_menu)

        # Popup Menu
        self.popMenu = QtGui.QMenu( self )
        self.popMenu.addAction( self.actionEdit )
        self.popMenu.addAction( self.actionDelete )
        self.popMenu.addSeparator()
        self.popMenu.addAction( self.actionAdd )

    def on_context_menu(self, point):
        self.popMenu.exec_( self.tree.mapToGlobal(point) )
```

Comment: You're talking about QTableWidget but your example uses a QTreeView. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to subclass QTableWidget and then implement your own `contextMenuEvent` method.  Then you can set different handling of the context menu event for each of your instances.  Here's a small example.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class MyTableWidget(QtGui.QTableWidget):

    def __init__(self, name='Table1', parent=None):
        super(MyTableWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.name = name

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        menu = QtGui.QMenu(self)

        Action = menu.addAction("I am a " + self.name + " Action")
        Action.triggered.connect(self.printName)

        menu.exec_(event.globalPos())

    def printName(self):
        print "Action triggered from " + self.name


class Main(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.table1 = MyTableWidget(name='Table1', parent=self)
        self.table2 = MyTableWidget(name='Table2', parent=self)

        layout.addWidget(self.table1)
        layout.addWidget(self.table2)
        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()

    app.exec_()
```